# How do I insert chart names as a variable from a grouped dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, charts

I am new to Python and programming in general.  I am trying to generate multiple horizontal bar graphs from a grouped dataframe.  I have been successful, in part, by using the following script:

```
#building dataframes for data plots

plotdf = pd.DataFrame(merge_df, columns= ['ppset_id', 'Cell Line', 'Undil_CT'])

plotdf = plotdf.dropna()

plotdf = plotdf.reset_index(drop=True)


plotdf.groupby('ppset_id').plot(x="Cell Line", y="Undil_CT", kind = "barh", xlim=(0,45), figsize=(11,8), legend=None)
```

The output is almost exactly what I want with data for each ppset_id in an individual chart, except each chart is missing the chart title.  I am trying to set the chart title for each graph to the unique ppset_id value associated with the data plotted, but haven't been able to find a way to do this after an extensive forum search.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Using seaborn tips dataset as an example.*

1. Store all axes in a variable (so you can later access each axis).
2. Access group names from **DataFrame.groupby(column_name).groups.keys()**
3. Both are equal length, so iterate over both and set each axis title to corresponding group name

Code example using seaborn tips dataset:

```
axes = tips.groupby('sex').plot()
group_names = tips.groupby('sex').groups.keys()
for ax, title in zip(axes, group_names):
    ax.set_title(title)
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a quick followup question that will definitely showcase my inexperience with python.  Since these graphs are generated by one line without an explicit loop: """plotdf.groupby('ppset_id').plot(x="Cell Line", y="Undil_CT", kind = "barh", xlim=(0,45), figsize=(11,8), legend=None)""" Is it possible to save each one in an individual .png or all in one .png  file to a specified file path through scripting?

Comment: FYI, this would probably do better as a separate question rather than a comment on an answered question. As far as I know, you could get individual plots saved to file by accessing corresponding figure from each axis and apply `savefig()` method as (0 here is what you would need to iterate to save all plots to individual files, providing different file_names): `axes[0].get_figure().savefig(file_name)`. Saving them as one file would require additional formatting and possibly different way of plotting, for which to explore comment is not really suitable.